# Can I upgrade from Drupal 7.10 directly to Drupal 7.12

Tags: updating

Should I upgrade from 7.10  to 7.11 first, then upgrade from 7.11 to 7.12?

Or can I just upgrade from 7.10 directly to Drupal 7.12?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can update directly to 7.12 without any problems. Drupal 7.11 contains security fixes while 7.12 contains bug fixes. Updating to 7.12 would also add the security fixes from 7.11.

Comment: This can get a bit confusing: 7.12 *compared to* 7.11 only contains bug fixes. So it contains the security fixes, too.

Comment: Yes indeed. 7.12 contains both security fixes (from 7.11) and also bug fixes.

Answer (score 3):

Theorically you can upgrade from any version to any version if you stay in the same major version (7.x), as new version contains all changes of the old ones.

This principe applies to contrib modules, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upgrade it but it will be nice practice to have backup of your source before upgrading your drupal to remain safe from issue like [this](http://drupal.org/node/1425342).

Also note that you haven't change or coded in any of drupal core files.

Comment: You should never alter code in the core files. If you need to alter core behaviour that should be done from a module or the theme so that upgrading isn't an issue.